# How does a scanf() inside printf() work?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

        int n;
        printf("%d\n",scanf("%d",&n));
        return 0;
}
```

I wonder why the output of this program is always '1' ?!
What's actually happening here ?

Comment: `scanf` returns a value from the function: the number of items converted, as the man page will tell you. The man page should be your first stop with any function you use.

Comment: You did not read anything on scanf(), did you? http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Comment: What answer do you get when you type in a non-digit character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@jishnu**, good question and the output which you're getting is also correct as you are only reading one value from standard input (`stdin`).

> `scanf()` reads the values supplied from standard input and return number of values successfully read from standard input (keyboard).
>
> In C, `printf()` returns the number of characters successfully written on the output and `scanf()` returns number of items successfully read. Visit https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-10/ and read more about it.

Have a look at the following 2 code samples.

> Try the below code online at http://rextester.com/HNJE76121.
>       //clang 3.8.0

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

    int n, n2;
    printf("%d\n",scanf("%d%d",&n, &n2));   //2
    return 0;
}
```

In your code, `scanf()` is reading only 1 value from the keyboad (`stdin`), that is why output is 1.

```
//clang 3.8.0

#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

    int n;
    printf("%d\n",scanf("%d",&n));   //1
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you wanted to use

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("%d\n", n);
```

but what you wrote is equivalent to

```
int n;
int num = scanf("%d", &n); // num is the number of successful reads.
printf("%d\n", num);
```

Comment: The intention of my question was just to know the reason behind the result as I encountered such an objective question in a book...Thank you

Comment: @jishnupramod, If I were you, I would drop that book. A book should teach principles and fundamental aspects of the language. Using questions like that is what I call "smart-assery". It's not teaching.

Answer (score 2):

The program is just about exactly equivalent to

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    int r = scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d\n", r);
    return 0;
}
```

So if you run this program, and if you type (say) 45, then `scanf` will read the 45, and assign it to `n`, and return 1 to tell you it has done so.  The program prints the value 1 returned by `scanf` (which is *not* the number *read* by `scanf`!).

Try running the program and typing "A", instead.  In that case `scanf` should return, and your program should print, 0.

Finally, if you can, try running the program and giving it no input at all.  If you're on Unix, Mac, or Linux, try typing control-D immediately after running your program (that is, without typing anything else), or run it with the input redirected:

```
myprog < /dev/null
```

On Windows, you might be able to type control-Z (perhaps followed by the Return key) to generate an end-of-file conditions.  In any of these cases, `scanf` should return, and your program should print, -1.

Answer (score 1):

In your program `scanf` returns 1 when successfully some value is taken by `scanf` into n and that is why you are always getting 1 from your `printf("%d\n",scanf("%d",&n));`.
You should modify your code like following

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

        int n;
        scanf("%d",&n);
        printf("%d\n",n);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: The intention of my question was just to know the reason behind the result...Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In [`man scanf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf),

> Return Value
>
> These functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.

In your program, it just match 1 input, so the function `scanf` will return 1, if you input an legal value that can match a `%d`, else it will return 0.

In your situation, you might always satisfy this requirements, so it *always* return 1.

Comment: The input format spec is `%d`. If an integer cannot be extracted from the input, `scanf` returns `0` - that is what the return value is for. That is not "always 1".

Comment: @WeatherVane I assumed that the author of question will always input a legal `%d`... It's my mistake, thank you.

Comment: Yes, the purpose of the return value is to detect if user did not enter a value that can be converted to the type.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` returns number of successful conversions. 
Try changing your `scanf` to as shown below.... 
you will notice printing 2 after inputting two valid integers.

```
int n1 =0;
int n2 =0;
int i = scanf("%d %d",&n1,&n2);
```

Comment: A more accurate term is "successful conversions".

Comment: True. I will change it.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` returns the number of successful conversion and assignments.  In your case, you're only scanning for one argument, so `scanf` will either return a `1` on success, a `0` on a *matching failure* (where the first non-whitespace input character is not a decimal digit), or `EOF` on end-of-file or error.

When you call `printf`, each of its arguments is *evaluated* and the result is passed to the function.  In this case, evaluation involves calling the `scanf` function.  The value returned by `scanf` is then passed to `printf`.

It's essentially the same as writing

```
int count = scanf( "%d", &n );
printf( "%d\n", count );
```

For giggles, see what happens when you enter `abc` or type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> on Windows).

Note that `printf` *also* returns a value (the number of bytes written to the stream), so you can write something ridiculous<sup>1</sup> like

```
printf( "num bytes printed = %d\n", printf( "num items read = %d\n", scanf( "%d", &n ) ) );
```

---

1. Joke.  Don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

**In `C` programming, `scanf()` takes the inputs from `stdin()` which is the keyboard and returns the number of successful inputs read
and `printf()` returns the number of characters written to `stdout()` which is the display monitor.**

*In your program `scanf()` is reading only one input which is getting returned and is printed by `printf()`. So, whatever may be the input the output is always 1 as it is reading only one input.*

Here take a look at this C program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

        int n, n2;
        printf("%d\n",scanf("%d %d",&n,&n2));
        return 0;
}
```

It takes input or reads two integers from `stdin()` using `scanf()`, so the output will always be 2.

*****Note: The output is 0 if your input is not integer, as it reads integer only.***

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of scanf() says the return value is:

`Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned (which may be zero in case a matching failure occurred before the first receiving argument was assigned), or EOF if input failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned.`

The code you would instead want is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("%d\n",scanf("%d",&n));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The intention of my question was just to know the reason behind the result...Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you use this code as an example,
It shows : warning: implicit declaration of function 'printf' [-Wimplicit-function declaration]

```
int main()
{
char b[40]; 
printf(" %d", scanf("%s", b));
getchar();
}
```

Return value : -1

Outputs of the functions like **printf** and **scanf** can be use as a parameter to another function.

Comment: You mean "Return values", not "Outputs". What you are trying to say with the implicit-declaration-warning is unclear to me.

Comment: Yeah, It’s the return value !

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` is a function which is integer return type function. It returns total number of conversion characters in it. For ex if a statement is written as :

```
int c;
c=scanf("%d %d %d");
printf("%d",c);
```

Then output of this program will be `3`.
This is because `scanf()` is integer return type function and it returns total no of conversion characters, thus being `3` conversion characters it will return `3` to `c`.
So in your code `scanf()` returns `1` to `printf()` and thus output of program is `1`.
This is because if more than one statement are used in `printf()` execution orders starts from right to left.
Thus `scanf()` is executed first followed by `printf()`.